# the table in html is rendering a comma without any reason

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, nodemailer

the table in html is rendering a comma without any reason i am using nodemailer and smtp google server i feel it is something with respect to the html but i am not able to figure out

[image]

```
const mailOptions = {
    from: "xyz@gmail.com",
    to: "yzx@gmail.com",
    subject: "Issue Persisting for long time",
    html:
      "<h2>These are the issues persisting for long time</h2><ul> " +
      `<table style="border: 1px solid black;" >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="border: 1px solid black;">description</th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid black;">department</th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Location</th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      ${data.map((item) => {
        return `
        <tr>
        <td>sdfsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsdf</td>
        </tr>`
      })}
    </tbody>
  </table>`,
  };
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      res.send(error);
    } else {
      console.log(mailOptions.text);
      res.send("Email sent: " + info.response);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `map` invocation returns an array here:

```js
    <tbody>
      ${data.map((item) => {
        return `
        <tr>
        <td>sdfsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsdf</td>
        </tr>`
      })}
    </tbody>
```

The default string representation of an array is the comma-separated representation of each of its elements.

You can fix it by stringifying the array yourself, e.g. change the `.map(..)` to `.map(..).join("")`.

Comment: yah thanks mate it worked and learnt a new thing

Comment: A good day then :-)

Comment: mate u have any idea of mapbox-gl

Comment: help me out in my recent post if u have i am not able to get it